# Node.js App Error: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have a Next.js app. I have an error with Mongodb. I couldn't solve this problem for a while. That's why I wanted ask you guys. I hope we can solve it. It's very important for me. Firstly I'll give you my server.js codes, after that I'll give you the error message from console.

Server.js file codes:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv/config')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('DB connected!')

  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

  app.prepare().then(()=>{
    const server = express()
  
    //ROUTES
    server.use(express.json())
    server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))
  
    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if(err) throw err
      console.log(`Server listen on http://127.0.0.1:${port}`)
    })
  
  })

})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('DB ERROR:', err)
})
```

Error message on console:

```
DB ERROR: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:684:11)
    at /home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:10
    at /home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1158:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:331:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodeApps/mywebsite-next/server.js:11:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

I have the link of Mongodb in my env file. Maybe the error causes because of this situation?

```
DATABASE=mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0.u4slu.mongodb.net/mydbusername?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: If you `console.log(process.env.DATABASE)` before doing `mongoose.connect`, do does it resolve to a fully form string with username, database, dbusername, etc all with the correct values? You're actual .env has all those values filled in right? You just replace them with <username> to protect them when posting here right?

Comment: When I do that, I see the link of Mongodb just like writed in the env file.

Comment: Yeah, you need to actually replace <username> with the actual username and <password> with the actual password and so on, those don't automatically get filled in for you. That answer by incbeatz is correct then.

Comment: Man, come on! I didn't write the real username and password to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your login credentials to your mongodb url code like this:

```
DATABASE=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.u4slu.mongodb.net/<dbusername>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

If you did already try to give the path to dotenv:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'ENV_FILENAME' });
```

Comment: I already did that but didn't write to the question because of security issues :) But I can try the second line of code. Where should I write it?

Comment: Replace it with your original require dotenv code and inside it put your path. Like if it’s in the source directory just write path: ‘config.env’

Comment: Thanks. It worked! I changed the config code with yours.