# Mongo/Mongoose will not pass a string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Attempting to connect to MongoDB via a follow-along, and I keep getting this error:

> > The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

Here is the code I'm working with:
.env file (I changed the username and password. The name is cluster0)

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.l94wepe.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Server.js

```
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI)

  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected to db");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Any help is appreciated, let me know what other info I can provide. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70585448/2282634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .env file has "MONGO_URI" and the JS file has "MONGODB_URI"

Comment: holy God thank you. I don't know why I didn't see that. What a dumb thing to be stuck on. Thank you.